# For a teams Tab Application, is it possible for a teams back navigation to load the tab on the FrameContext (as per a reload)

Tags: microsoft-teams

I've created a custom teams tab app, that has sub views from its main view. These can have links on them to other teams content which we load using the SDK method executeDeepLink().

The problem is that after clicking on a link, which loads another tab in Teams, a back navigate in the Teams client loads the custom application tab on the default main view and we need it to load on the sub view that was displayed when the link was clicked.

We have tried using setFrameContext(). This works for reloading the tab with the reload button, but does not effect the reloading of the tab from a back navigation.

Is there anyway to get the back navigation in teams to work as desired? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to go back to the same page on back navigation? Teams does not store the session. So the next time you come back to the tab, the tab gets reloaded.

Comment: Yes, I was hoping there would be a way for back navigation to work the same way as reload does after calling setFrameContext() and reload the tab using the the contentUrl set in the FrameContext, otherwise there is no way to use visit a linked teams document and return to the page you were looking at within a tab.

Comment: You could try creating [deeplinks to tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links) using subentity id's but it will reload your tab and the session will not be stored.